# unable to play track not encoded correctly when backword or forward skip inside playback of the trac

Tags: sonos

I'm developing Soap service for Sonos. The service is partially accepted BY SONOS. But still having the problems that some of the mp3 tracks lead to "unable to play track not encoded correctly" when making skip (forward or backward) during playing the track (inside the track). I have compared encoding procedure for 'good' and 'bad' tracks and I don't see any real reason that part of them doesn't make skip inside the track. I will appreciate very much any hint related to this issue.

Best regards,

Krzys

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to use HLS? Can you provide any more information on the calls and responses that you are sending or on the exact text of the error messaging you are seeing?

Comment: No we don't use HLS. This is the playing content stored in Amazone cloud S3. During the normal playback of the songs (Mp3) user can click to move forward and backword in the track. In this case SONOS sends request to request content using byte ranges. The proper request is send to the S3. For part of the tracks (40%) the message appears: "Unable to play 'song title'- the track is not encoded correctly" . See:https://en.community.sonos.com/troubleshooting-228999/skipping-through-a-track-causes-encoding-error-6736984. please help us.

Comment: Is there any other way to communicate to solve the issue? regards, Krzys